# Website Not Fully Encrypted Error

Tags: php, html, css, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on http://usborrow.com and installed a GeoTrust Business ID SSL Certificate. The site is saying that it is not fully encrypted and the seal won't appear at the bottom of the page. I can't seem to find any non https references in the site. Any support is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing some external 3rd party libs such as Google's hosted jquery lib with http. eg.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Google fonts and jQuery calls are not over SSL amongst other things:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/aoc1gun.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, some of your external resources are hard-coded to use http.

It's good practice to leave out the http / https part of the url, which makes the browser request it over the same protocol as the current page. (there is no need to request a css file over https unless your page is https!)

Example:

```
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Obviously, some services don't provide an https version, in which case you'll need to host a copy yourself if you want your seal to appear.